# add observer and selector method not executing

Tags: ios, swift3

[image: My story board image is below]

When the user clicked in a cell it will go to the detail view controller here I post a notification with the selected index(object of a class). In detail view controller I used a container view. In this container view, I used a page view controller having two view controllers let's say A and B correspondingly. Both these two view controllers I created add observer method. But only 'A' view controller is registering for the notification. How can I get the selected index(object of a class) in B view controller..?

Code of detail View controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: mynotificationkey), object: nil, userInfo: ["object": self.treatobj])



}




override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pageView2" {
       if let destination = segue.destination as? PageViewController {
            destination.treatmentObject = treatobj



        }



    }

}
```

code of First View Controller that its executing fine

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(display(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: mynotificationkey), object: nil)

      }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


  func display(notification: Notification){
    if let object = notification.userInfo {
        if let obj = object["object"] {

            treatObject = obj as! TreatMents
            print(treatObject)
            self.detailTitleLabel.text = treatObject.trtName
            self.DesctextView.text = treatObject.desc1




        }
    }

}
```

code of second view controller that does not execute add observer

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    about.text = treatObj.aboutkerala
    //benifits = treatObj.benifits!



  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notfrecieved(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: mynotificationkey), object: nil)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func notfrecieved(notification: Notification) {

    if let object = notification.userInfo {
        if let obj = object["object"] {
            print(obj)
            treatObj = obj as! TreatMents
            about.text = treatObj.aboutkerala
            benifits = treatObj.benifits!
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


        }
    }

}
```

code of Page view controller

```
    class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


var treatmentObject = TreatMents()

lazy var VCArray : [UIViewController] = {

    return [self.VCInstance(name: "DescFisrtVC"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "DescSecondVC"),
            ]
}()


private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {

  return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)


}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }


    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return VCArray.last
    }

    guard VCArray.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }



    return VCArray[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < VCArray.count else {
        return VCArray.first
    }

    guard VCArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }


    return VCArray[nextIndex]

}


// A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented, transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll', and navigation orientation is 'UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal'.
// Both methods are called in response to a 'setViewControllers:...' call, but the presentation index is updated automatically in the case of gesture-driven navigation.

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    return VCArray.count
}


public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {


    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewcontrollerIndex = VCArray.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }

    return firstViewcontrollerIndex
}
override func viewDidLoad() {

           super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self


    if let firstVc = VCArray.first {

        setViewControllers([firstVc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: at where you are post this notification  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: mynotificationkey). ?

Comment: you need to use different key for notification.

Comment: I declared a global variable as mynotificationkey and stored a value to that variable

Answer (score 0):

From the flow it looks to me that the two VCs in UIPageViewControllers didn't load yet when you are posting the notification.

Have a look at the [explanation given in doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller):

> When defining a page view controller interface, **you can provide the
>   content view controllers one at a time (or two at a time, depending
>   upon the spine position and double-sided state) or as-needed using a
>   data source. When providing content view controllers one at a time,
>   you use the setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)
>   method to set the current content view controllers**. To support
>   gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using
>   a data source object.

So my guess is that since one page is loaded at a time, so your second controller didn't register for this event.

I have an objection on this process design using NSNotification, since from your code it looks to me that you want to evaluate your `TreatMents` objects on both screen when they gets load, IMHO you can either use `Singleton` concept (using session) or use [`KVO`](https://cocoacasts.com/key-value-observing-kvo-and-swift-3/) to fix this problem.

**EDIT:**

In PageViewController you implement these two functions:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?   
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

that returns a VC from VCArray like:

```
return VCArray[previousIndex]
```

You also have `treatmentObject` in PageViewController, can you pass this variable to your two viewcontrollers while fetching it in above delegate functions like:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }


    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return VCArray.last
    }

    guard VCArray.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    let VC = VCArray[previousIndex]      // <------ Check this out
    VC.treatObj = self.treatmentObject;  // <------ Check this out

    return VC
}
```

Or you can also save your selected treatment in session and retrieve it in two view controllers.

Comment: In the table view, it displays many numbers of treatments. All the details are stored inside a class called Treatments and its objects are stored in a treatment array. When the user selects a cell I want to pass the selected treatment object from the treatment array to the two view controllers of the UIPageViewController...

Comment: I checked this method. But gives an error "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'treatObj'"

Comment: Don't you have this `treatObject = obj as! TreatMents` in your view controller ?

Comment: Yeah I have an object for Treatments Class as treatObject in my view controller

Comment: So this way you can pass `VC.treatObj = self.treatmentObject;  // <------ Check this out` selected treatment object from page view controller to viewcontroller in a page.

Comment: Let me check once more. Thanks for your fast reply

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to  NotificationCenter then you need to load that class in memory first .
- If you are added NotificationCenter in class but that class not loaded so this will be not working .